# Only part of a webpage view is loading in uiwebview, how do i get the rest of it loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Im trying to get a web page to load in a uiwebview. The majority of the page loads but the table on the page doesnt load for me. Does anyone know why this might be?
The table is at this url  http://www.irishrugby.ie/rugby/aib_league_results_and_fixtures.php

Comment: What version of iOS do you have?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of UIwebView?

Comment: @Kashiv - I dnt know how to post a screen shot of it on here

Comment: @user643160 you can post in on http://tinypic.com (as an example) and then paste a link ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick app with a web view, gave it that url, and it works fine, shows the whole table.  Do you have scrolling disabled somehow?

[image]

Comment: i dnt think i have scrolling disabled.the main code that i added is :                                                            NSString *urlAddress =@"http://www.irishrugby.ie/rugby/aib_league_results_and_fixtures.php";                                                                     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

Comment: Bring up your web page in the simulator, grab a screen shot (Shift-Command-4).  Then in SO, edit your answer, tap the image icon (6th from left), and upload your screen shot.